# Deploy em Projetos Laravel

Tags: laravel, deploy

Olá!

Depois de pronto um projeto em Laravel, quais pastas e arquivos realmente são úteis para fazer o upload para o servidor?

Atualmente eu uso tudo e acho meio pesado.

Comment: Todas as pastas do projeto... !!!

Comment: Puxa vida! rsrs

Comment: Não é como o java web que a gente só cria um .war e já era rsrs

Comment: Existe quando o servidor se comunica com repositórios tipo Git mas no seu caso pelo que percebi pra resumir é tudo mesmo

Comment: Beleza.Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Assim que seu projeto utilizando Laravel é publicado em produção, são recomendados algumas configurações para otimizá-lo.

1.No arquivo **.env** trocar para o novo environment.

```
APP_ENV=production
```

2.Otimização do Autoloader.

```
composer install --optimize-autoloader
```

3.Esta configuração converte todos os arquivos de configurações do Laravel em um único arquivo de cache, reduzindo o número de caminhos que o framework precisará realizar, resultando em um tempo menor de execução.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

4.Caso seu projeto possua um número grande de rotas, é recomendado utilizar o comando abaixo para reduzir suas rotas em uma única função junto aos arquivos de cache, melhorando a performance do site.

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Maiores informações na documentação: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/deployment#optimization

Comment: posso fazer isso antes de enviar para o servidor de produção?

Comment: Deu o seguinte problema `Logiexception : Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses closure`

Segundo [esse link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7319#issuecomment-73362932) é porque provavelmente eu tenho rotas dentro de grupo